# Get events data from Google Analytics API with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I want to get events of one of my apps that uses Google Analytics.
I am little confused with example given in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide?hl=en#intro). I make it work but i don't understand how to use it for my case.

```
require_once 'GA/vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

After this code I want to get events data - how should I specify counter id, and event info?

Using Query Explorer I managed to created query that I need:

```
googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A111111&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=2016-05-11&metrics=ga%3AtotalEvents&dimensions=ga%3AeventLabel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by counter id.  You have your analytics service you just need to make the request now.

```
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:AeventLabel');  
// requesting the data  
$data = $analytics->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "30daysAgo", "2016-05-11", "ga:totalEvents", $params );
// displaying the data
foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
            print "ga:AeventLabel ".$row[0]." ga:totalEvents ".$row[1]";     
        }
```

Comment: Finally I have got what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I use [this class](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) with the following code and it works well:

```
require 'GoogleAPI/gapi.class.php';
define('ga_profile_id','YOUR-DEV-ID');

$ga = new gapi('YOUR-DEV-ID@developer.gserviceaccount.com','GoogleAPI/cert.p12');

$ga->requestReportData('YOUR-APP-ID',array('eventAction'),array('visitors'),null,"eventAction==loginViaWebsite",$"2016-05-11","2016-05-11");
$logins = $ga->getResults();
if($logins) $logins = $logins[0]->getMetrics();
```